# Generate a dynamic html in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, innerhtml, dynamic-html

I'm an `Angular 1.5` expert developer, on our new project we're using `Angular 7` for building a dynamic complicated form, it may have multiple fields:

1. Input
2. Button
3. Custom components
4. Dropdown
5. Lit item

I addition may it have dependencies between fields, it means that there's a need to use `*ngIf` in some situation for a specific field.
Now, what I'm thinking to do is to load the `How the form should looks` from an external JSON file, like this example:

```
 {
  'type': 'Dropdown',
  'label': 'Service',
  'model': {
    'defaultValue': 'TEST1',
    'name': 'SERVICE',
    'dropDownModel': {
      'staticValues': [{
        'label': 'Test 1',
        'value': 'TEST1'
      }, {
        'label': 'Test 2',
        'value': 'TEST2'
      }, {
        'label': 'Test 3',
        'value': 'TEST3'
      }]
    }
  }
```

Then, I go over the JSON and generate a dynamic HTML as it described on the JSON. Notice that on the `model` there's a `name` property that it should be connected to the `ngModel`, and it should be added to the `viewModel` of the component.

After checking on articles related to this I found some of them are using `[innerHtml]` but it's not worked for me if I'm adding `ngModel` to the generated field.
Also, I tried to use `Reactive Forms` and notice that I should write some static code on HTML.
Can you please assist for best practice how to do this thing?

Comment: How could an AngularJS developper not know that **you do not manipulate the DOM yourself in Angular** (all versions of it) ? Other than that, you could try taking a look at [the dynamic form doc](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

Comment: Did you get the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is exact the same problem I was working on last week.

After long research I come to:

https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form

You might take look at this.